# Does $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k$ converge uniformly where f maps from $[0, 3/4]$ to reals

Tags: uniform-convergence

Does  $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k$ converge uniformly where f maps from $[0, 3/4]$ to reals?

I found the pointwise limit to be $\frac{1}{1-x} $for $ x \in (0, 3/4]$ and $0$ for $x=0$. I do not know how to proceed

Comment: It's $1$ for $x = 0$

Comment: $|\frac{1}{1-x}-f_n(x)|\leq |x|^{n+1}+|x|^{n+2}+...=\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{1-|x|}\leq(3/4)^{n+1}$ for $x\in[0,3/4]$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod That shows that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $(0,3/4]$ but not on $[0,3/4]$.

Comment: @Math1000 there is no issue at $0$. The only endpoint that could cause problems is at $1$ but that is excluded from the domain. Hence the convergence is, in fact, uniform.

Comment: @Math1000 That shows everything that needs to be shown. You review what you wrote.

Comment: Hmm, if we take $0^0=1$ then I suppose it is okay. Never mind.

Comment: Indeed, $\lim_{x\to 0}x^0=1$ so we may safely define $f_n(0)=1$. Which implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(0) = \frac1{1-0}=1$. So indeed by the Weierstrass M-test the series converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe by the geometric series summation formula that
$$
f_n(x)=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x},
$$
and also let $f(x)=1/(1-x)$ denote the limit function. Then
$$
|f(x)-f_n(x)|=\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{|1-x|}.
$$
To establish uniform convergence, we must show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ - where the bounds do not depend on the value of $x$. In this case, observe from $1-x\geq \tfrac14$ and $x\leq \tfrac34$ that we obtain the uniform bound
$$
|f(x)-f_n(x)|\leq 4 \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n+1},
$$
allowing you to choose the appropriate $N$ given $\epsilon$, as required.